# Remove www folder from KCFinder image path

Tags: javascript, php, kcfinder

I am using CKEditor with KCFinder for uploading images and files on Nette project. Upload works perfectly, but KCFinder returns absolute path on web server instead of URL. Than I get www/upload/images/test.jpg instead of http://mypage.com/upload/images or /upload/images.

Does somebody know, where and how can I solve this please?

Part of my KCFinder config.php:

```
$_CONFIG = array(


// GENERAL SETTINGS

    'disabled' => false,
    'uploadURL' => "../../upload",
    'uploadDir' => "",
    'theme' => "dark",
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to change folder permissions... Solved the problem